# How to keep the current year and add new year?

Tags: php, laravel

The idea I need to add a new year to my select box  when it comes like we in 2020 so I need when 2021 just add it to my select box with keep 2020 as well without delete it

I used the date('Y') it just for now

```
<option value="{{ date('Y') }}"> {{ date('Y') }} </option>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I assume you are using a templating engine?

Comment: You could generate the `<option>` elements in a loop, iterating from some starting year up to the current year. How far back do you want the years to go?

Comment: @showdev the idea: Now we are in 2020 right? so when 2021 comes just add it to my select dynamic without remove 2020( means another way now just show 2020 but when we enter in 2021 just add it without remove 2020 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to start with 2020 and add new years as they arrive, I suggest using a `for` loop to iterate from 2020 to the current year.

Something like this:

```
for ($year=2020; $year<=date('Y'); $year++) {
   echo "<option>$year</option>";
}
```

Or if using Laravel/Blade:

```
@for ($year=2020; $year<=date('Y'); $year++)
    <option>{{ $year }}</option>
@endfor
```

Or even:

```
{{ Form::selectRange('year', 2020, date('Y')) }}
```

For reference:
[PHP Control Structures - *for* loops](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)
[Laravel - Templates - Other Blade Control Structures (see Loops)](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#other-blade-control-structures)
[Laravel - Forms & HTML - Drop-Down Lists (see selectRange)](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists)

Answer (score 1):

you can test it

```
date('Y', strtotime('+1 year'))
```

Comment: the idea: Now we are in 2020 right? so when 2021 comes just add it to my select dynamic without remove 2020( means another way now just show 2020 but when we enter in 2021 just add it without remove 2020 )

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="{{ date_create('next year')->format('Y') }}"> {{ date_create('next year')->format('Y') }} </option>
```

`value` attribute is optional on `<option>`. If your value is the same as your contents you can remove the value attribute.

Comment: the idea: Now we are in 2020 right? so when 2021 comes just add it to my select dynamic without remove 2020( means another way now just show 2020 but when we enter in 2021 just add it without remove 2020 )